# Nvidia Overclock and Fan control

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, gpu

I am trying to overclock (or at least control the fan speed on) a couple 1080tis I am using to mine on a ubuntu 18.04 system.

The problem is to enable overclocking `coolbits` need to be set in Xorg.conf. I have tried using `ǹvidea-xconfig` but it only generates a config with one card. When attempting to add another 'device' to the config it is completely ignored.

Ideally I would like to set the config to have 3 devices. 2 of the 1080tis with coolbits set to use for mining and the onboard intel graphics used for driving the display.

Even when i can set coolbits for the one card it overclocks however if i set GPUCurrentFanSpeed in nvidia-settings it reports an unknown error when assigning the value.